# Weird memory allocation error

Tags: php

I encounter with the notorious memory allocation bug.
So, I have the following code:

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|MPL[] $mpls */
foreach ($mpls as $index => $mpl) {
    $mplMIDs = [];
    $mpl->getMIDs(false, false)->each(function(MID $mid) use (&$mplMIDs) {
        if ($mid->isSingleLinked()) {
            $mplMIDs[] = $mid->mid_key;
        }
    });

    if (!$mplMIDs) {
        // most of the times the code enters here
        unset($mpls[$index]);
    }
    gc_collect_cycles() // working only if this adds this row
}
```

As you can see I have. `$mpls` array, for each `$mpl` I fetch it's `MIDs` from the database (`getMIDs` function) and then for each `MID` I check if it's what I called `singleLinked` (also call to the database).
The point is that I have an array of object that I insert to them more objects and to those objects insert more objects:

```
$mpls (array of objects) [
   $mpl (object) {
       $mids (array of objects) {
            $entities (array of objects)
       }
   }
   ... more $mpls... 
]
```

For some reason, the memory is getting full quickly (1GB in about 20 seconds!) I thought that the unset should fix it, but it helps only if I enforce garbage collection by `gc_collect_cycles`
Maybe it's happening because the object is "deep"?

PHP version: PHP 5.6.30
Error I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /larvael/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 303
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? The allocated memory grows, so... ?

Comment: How big are the objects? Make a var_dump of an object, if the resultsite are too big consider making what you can static, it lowers the amount of memory and instance uses a lot in some cases.

Comment: @zerkms it's crash, and maybe if the whole data is more than 1GB, why it's not clean on each iteration because the `unset`

Comment: @MarceloStaudt the objects are big, but not more than 10 MB (ever..), thanks for the static idea, but I don't get why them not get cleaned each iteration! it's freak me out!

Comment: @Michael elaborate "crash". Is it killed by OOM killer? Or segfaulted? Or what exactly?

Comment: "consider making what you can static" --- this makes very little sense to me, given that statics have program-life storage length thus never collected automatically. And given that making something static does not automagically help it less memory hungry.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, I forgot to attach the error I got from php, added it to the question.

Comment: you said it only works if you add garbage collection! why dont you keep the garbage collection?! Garbage collection is your solution

Comment: @AhmadHajjar because enforcing garbage collection each iteration is pretty heavy and also, why the internal collection algorithm not free the memory by itself as it should do, maybe I'm doing something wrong in my code...

Answer (score 0):

php.ini file  In case you can’t find the php.ini file or do not have access to it, then open up the file which was throwing the error
ini_set(“memory_limit”,”16M“);

Comment: Why is this a solution? His memory limit is currently about 1GB, reducing it would cause the error to happen earlier...

Comment: memery limit is increated for your php.in file